# How to decide whether a Tic-tac-toe game has ended?

Tags: algorithm, tic-tac-toe

The rule of tic-tac-toe game is as follows:
when there are three consecutive x's or o's, or all places have been occupied, the game is over.

For example the following image shows this rule:

[image: this picture]

This can be achieved by first using for loop to examine column, row, diagonal, anti-diagnal respectively and then checking whether the whole board has been full. But I think this may cause the code to be very long-winded. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Well this could have 2 kinds of answers. First is implementation based. What implementation are you using? Second a general answer. I think however you will have to traverse each block at least once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winning only happens once one player has taken a turn. There turn will only affect a row and a column and sometimes diagonals. This means that you only need to check some rather of the rows, columns and diagonals instead of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Fast in terms of computation time would be to check each winning position directly. Of course you can speed this up by fixing a round and then only check the winning positions that contain the position where a user has placed its mark in this round.

Here are all winning positions and a working method:

```
public boolean hasWinner() {
    return
        (board[0] != null && board[0] == board[1] && board[0] == board[2])
      ||(board[3] != null && board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5])
      ||(board[6] != null && board[6] == board[7] && board[6] == board[8])
      ||(board[0] != null && board[0] == board[3] && board[0] == board[6])
      ||(board[1] != null && board[1] == board[4] && board[1] == board[7])
      ||(board[2] != null && board[2] == board[5] && board[2] == board[8])
      ||(board[0] != null && board[0] == board[4] && board[0] == board[8])
      ||(board[2] != null && board[2] == board[4] && board[2] == board[6]);
}
```

The indices identify the board as:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

As said, if a player places its mark at `board[4]` (that is the center) you would just need to check:

```
(board[3] != null && board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5])
||(board[1] != null && board[1] == board[4] && board[1] == board[7])
||(board[0] != null && board[0] == board[4] && board[0] == board[8])
||(board[2] != null && board[2] == board[4] && board[2] == board[6])
```

That are the two straight and the two diagonal winning scenarios. Other winning scenarios are not affected by `board[4]` and can not lead to a winning position in this round.

You could use a `Map<Index, Set<WinningScenarios>>` to access all scenarios to check given the index or something similar. If your board is big you could also directly compute the other positions that need to be checked.

For checking whether the game halts and both loose you can just remember the number of placed marks (or rounds) and increase it every round. If the counter reaches `board.length` then all fields have been set.